# After clicking hyperlink in view, function in controller file is not responding - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to echo by calling register method in Home.php controller page (in fact I am calling another page in register method) after clicking "Click here to register" hyperlink in View. However, I am getting a Page not found error. Not sure whats happening.

I checked few solutions in stackoverflow but could not be able to figure out the issue. Thanks in advance. Really Appreciated!

This is my Controller file called Home.php:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->database();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        //$this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('index_login');
        //echo "hjkaj";

    }

    public function register()
    {
        // $this->load->view('Register');
        echo "welcome to ksj";
    }

}
?>
```

This is my View file called index_login.php:

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('url');
?>

<form class="form-horizontal container well" action="search.php" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">UserName</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-md-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <b>New User?</b></br> <a href="<?php
echo "index.php/home/register";
?>"> Click here to register</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Paste this code in .htaccess You dont need to write index.php every time. RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L,PT]

Answer (score 1):

add base_url() funtion with your link.

```
<b>New User?</b></br> <a href="<?php
echo base_url()."index.php/home/register";
?>"> Click here to register</a>
```

Comment: Thanks reza for response. I have to format link from "index.php/home/register" to "home/register". Issue is fixed now :)